# Yii2 запуск скрипта после подгрузки одного из нескольких Pjax

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, pjax

Есть чат на yii2. В чате для подгрузки сообщений и смены диалогов используется pjax. Есть скрипт, который листает в конец сообщения. Один pjax виджет вложен в другой. (id разные).

Внешний pjax обновляется при выборе диалога и при отправке сообщения. Внутренний pjax обновляется раз в 10 сек.

Выглядит всё это примерно так:

```
...
//внешний pjax
<?php Pjax::begin([
  'id' => 'all-chat',
  'timeout' => 5000,
  'formSelector' => '.input_msg_write'
]) ?>
  ...
  //некоторый код
  ...
  <div class="msg_history"> //блок с сообщениями, который нужно пролистать вниз
  //внутренний pjax
  <?php Pjax::begin([
    'id' => 'list-messages',
    'timeout' => 5000,
    'enablePushState' => false,
    'formSelector' => false,
    'linkSelector' => false
  ]) ?>
    ...
    //тут сообщения которые обновляются раз в 10 сек
    ...
  <?php Pjax::end() ?>
  </div>
  ...
  //еще немного кода
  ...
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
...
```

Нужно чтоб скрипт который листает в конец сообщения срабатывал только при обновлении внешнего pjax, но не срабатывал при обновлении внутреннего.

Пробовал писать вот так:

```
$('#all-chat').on('pjax:success',function () {
  scrollTopChat();
})
```

но тогда сообщения прокручиваются при обновлении любого из двух pjax-ов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проверкой внутри скрипта какой контейнер был обновлен:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success',function (event, data, status, xhr, option) {
     if (option.container.selector == '#all-chat') {
         scrollTopChat();
     }
})
```

Так нужный скрипт запускается после обновления нужного контейнера Pjax, а не при любом обновлении

Comment: Данный ответ полностью удовлетворяет моему вопросу. Проблема решается таким скриптом, так что я считаю, что это достаточно исчерпывающий ответ на данный вопрос.